# How to get the parent element from child element?

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I am trying to get the parent element of the object.

```
  obj.GetROProperty("parent").GetROProperty("innertext")
```

But I am getting whole html element instead of div block.

Answer (score 0):

UFT *flattens* the DOM so that (by default) all HTML elements are children of the document (`Page` or `Frame`). If you want the actual DOM parent you can use the [`.Object`](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.50/UFT_Help/Subsystems/FunctionReference/Subsystems/OMRHelp/OMRHelp.htm#Common_Methods_and_Properties/Common_Methods_and_Properties.html#Object) property

```
MsgBox obj.Object.parentElement.textContent
```